# ReducyByKeyAndWindowByCount in Spark stateful streaming aggegations

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, reduce, apache-spark-dataset

I've to inner join two relational tables extracted from Oracle.

Actually i want to perform 1-to-1 join to get one row per primary key with aggegated in list values from the second table. So before joining 1-to-1 two tables i have to reduce all my rows by key to a 1 with values kept in the list.

Here is the illustration of what i need:
[![tables aggregation][1]][1]

And here i've met a problem which is when to stop aggegation for my key and pass aggegated entity to the next step. Spark offers solutions for that by providing window intervals and watermaking for late data. And so assumption for keeping data consistency is the time it receives the data. It is feasible and applicable for infinite datasets but in my case i exactly know the count of aggegations for each key. For exampe for customer_id 1000 i know exactly that there are only 3 products and after i've aggegated 3 products i know that i can stop aggegation now and go to the next streaming step in my pipeline. How can this solution be implemented using Spark and streaming? I know there is reduceByKeyAndWindow operation but in my case i need something like reduceByKeyAndWindowByCount.

Count will be stored in a static dataset or simply store it in a row as an additional data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we've decided to switch from streaming to core spark with batch processing because we have finite dataset and that thing works well for our use case. We've came to a conclusion that spark streaming was designed for processing continuous (which was actually obvious only from it's naming) datasets. And thats why we have only window intervals by time and watermarks to correct network or other delays during transportation. We've also found our design with counters ugly, complex and in the other words bad. It is a live example of a bad design and such growing complexity was a marker that we were moving in the wrong direction and were trying to use a tool for a purpose it was not designed for.